# Distance calculated from MongoDB geoNear command is wrong

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model like the following:

```
var locSchema = new Schema({
    loc:{
        type:[Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    }
});
```

And, I'm using $geoNear command like this:

```
Location.aggregate([{
        "$geoNear": {
            "near": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [parseInt(req.query.longitude), parseInt(req.query.latitude)]
            },
            "spherical": true,
            "distanceField": "distance"
        }
    });
```

I'm uploading the longitude and latitude from a location and saving it in the model. And, I'm retrieving the models using the same location in `geoNear` command. That is **same longitude and latitude.**

But, in the result, I have `distance` as a *big* float where I should get 0 (or at least near 0).

```
{
  _id: "578ca6613525d44b3f5171b8",
  loc: [
    79.9811093,
    14.450403300000001
  ],
  distance: 117139.297675591
}
```

I tried the `distanceMultiplier` but that does not seem to work. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: long and lat are not integers `parseInt`

Comment: oh.. I actually had a problem with using strings. Should I use floats? I guess I should. :)